# How to convert array element to Map[String,String] in spark 2.2 with java

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am using spark 2.2 and java 1.8

sample XML format -

```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
         <!-- Generated by Oracle DVM Editor version 1.0 at [9/6/11 5:14 PM]. 
         -->
      <dvm name="CIHSubscriptionTypeMapping" xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/dvm">
       <description>
      </description>
     <columns>
       <column name="SSPMW"/>
       <column name="CIH"/>
      </columns>
    <rows>   

      <row>
        <cell>ute.recordClass</cell>
        <cell>sku_type</cell>
      </row>    
      <row>
        <cell>ute.name.en</cell>
        <cell>name_en</cell>
      </row>

     </rows>
 </dvm>
```

Reading XML file in spark with java API -

```
Dataset<Row> xmlDF =spark.read()
    .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
    .options("rowTag","row")
    .load("sample.xml");



xmlDF.printSchema()

root
 |-- cell: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)


xmlDF.show(false)


cell
================
         [ute.recordClass, sku_type] 
         [ute.name.en, name_en]
```

I want convert above "cell" column to Lookup Map(String,String) and later will use it for broadcast.

Example - (ute.sku.price,list_price)......

Can some one help on this?.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map` inbuilt function as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.*;

xmlDF.select(functions.map(functions.col("cell").getItem(0), functions.col("cell").getItem(1)).as("cell")).show(false);
```

which should give you

```
+-----------------------------+
|cell                         |
+-----------------------------+
|[ute.recordClass -> sku_type]|
|[ute.name.en -> name_en]     |
+-----------------------------+

root
 |-- cell: map (nullable = false)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
```

**Update**

You commented as you **want in just java map**. For that you can use following method

```
    List<Row> rows = xmlDF.select(functions.col("cell").getItem(0).as("key"), functions.col("cell").getItem(1).as("value")).collectAsList();
    Map<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for(Row row : rows){
        hashMap.put(row.getString(0), row.getString(1));
    }
```

`hashMap` is a java map.

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: Thanks Ramesh. I want above output in just java map. Can you please help on this?.Thx

Comment: @Sekhar I have updated the answer. if the answer is helpful please consider accepting it

Comment: Thanks Ramesh for your help.